# Explicit differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you help me to find all solutions of differential equation $y'^2-(x+y)y'+xy=0$?

I wrote this equation as product of explicit equations:

$$(y'-x)(y'-y)=0$$

Then I found zeroes: $y'-x=0 \Longrightarrow y'=x \Longrightarrow y=\frac{x^2}2+C_1$

$y'=0$ I don't know what to do here. Maybe to solve as equation 'without $x$'? Am I doing this right?

Comment: see this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27^2-%28x%2By%29y%27%2Bxy%3D0

Comment: copy whole part ,not only blue

Comment: so, it's good what I did? how did it get y=C1e^x?

Comment: see solution i have posted

Answer (score 3):

Your second equation is not $y'=0$ as you write in the question, but $y'-y=0$, in other words $y'=y$. This has the well-known solution $y=C_2e^x$.

So now you have the solutions $y=\frac{x^2}2+C_1$ and $y=C_2 e^x$. Now, for the most difficult part of the trick, you need to find all ways to glue *intervals* of these solutions together so the derivative matches across the glue point ... which means (consult the differential equations again!) that the gluing point(s) has to lie on the line $x=y$.

For example one solution among many would be $y=\cases{e^{x-1}&\text{for }x\le 1\\ \frac{x^2+1}2&\text{for }x\ge 1}$.

On the other hand, this gluing-together doesn't involve anything specific to differential equations, so perhaps you can take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I missed y in y'=y, thanks. No, I don't know what to do after I found solutions I wrote :(

Comment: Does the explicit example I've just added help?

Comment: Frankly I dont understand this talk about "glue".  Why cant both solutions be valid across the entire domains?  They both work everywhere, after all, if you plugged them in.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: Each of the "base" solutions is valid across the entire domain, but there are _additional_ solutions that can be made by using different base solutions in different intervals of the $x$ axis. So if one is interested in finding the set of _all_ solutions, as the OP wanted, then these combined solutions need to be enumerated too.

Answer (score 1):

The second part is $y'-y = 0 \Rightarrow y' = y \Rightarrow y = C_2e^x$

Comment: I've just realized that y'=y is equation that separates variables :) Thank you :) Can you look at other problem I posted?

Answer (score 0):

$y'-y=0$, so it means that $y'=y$  this is only if $y$ is exponential function $y=ce^x$
if $y'-x=0$  it means that  $y'=x$  or $\frac{dy}{dx}=x$ integrate both we get  $y=(x^2)/2+c$

Comment: Here's a tip: enclose your math formulas between dollar signs; it will be easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for the tip :) I didn't know how to write correctly :)